# google maps, how to disable marker icons from being dragged around?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have noticed that in most google maps you can not drag the marker icon into your address bar and see or download the icon .png file itself. Rather then you hover your cursor over the marker, you can see javascript:void(0).

How is that achieved? Thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like markers in the [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) cannot be dragged to the address bar, while markers in the [v2 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/) can.

The following v3 example does not allow the marker to move around (tested in Firefox and Chrome). It also shows `javascript:void(0)` in the status bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
  <title>Google Maps API No Marker Dragging v3</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.00, -25.00),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      map: map
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[Google Maps API No Marker Dragging v3 http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/570/nodrag.jpg](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/570/nodrag.jpg)

On the other hand, the same example using the v2 API, allows the marker to be dragged to the address bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
  <title>Google Maps API No Marker Dragging v2</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()">
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(35.00, -25.00), 2);
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(map.getCenter()));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[Google Maps API No Marker Dragging v2 http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/8330/yesdrag.jpg](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/8330/yesdrag.jpg)